# awk date to epoch in log file and print other columns also

Tags: bash, perl, awk, timestamp, epoch

I have a log file where i need to output the DATE and some status codes. Also i`m using || as delimiter and remove unwanted symbols from the data. Here is how it looks like:

```
cat logfile.log | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\\|\\|" } { gsub("/","-")  sub(":", " ") gsub("\\[", "") gsub("\\+0000]", "")}; { print $15 $12 }' | uniq -c
```

This outputs:

```
  22  25-Jan-2016 01:53:52  85.10.210.199
  1   25-Jan-2016 01:53:52   66.249.93.77
  18  25-Jan-2016 01:53:52   85.10.210.199
  1   25-Jan-2016 01:53:52   88.232.191.231
```

After this i need to convert the time to epoch and still print column $1 and $3

I want to achive:

```
  22  1453686832  85.10.210.199
  1   1453686832   66.249.93.77
  18  1453686832   85.10.210.199
  1   1453686832   88.232.191.231
```

I can transform the date to epoch but i lose the other columns. How can i keep them also with transformed time?

This is my RAW log file:

```
[] ||  ||  ||  || [] || http || 40080 || 176.237.167.102 || [] || [-] || [0.072] || 176.237.167.102 || - || - || [25/Jan/2016:06:30:26 +0000] || "POST /checknewmsg HTTP/1.1" || 200 || 265 || 895 || "http://google.com/post” || "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36" || "-" || [TR]
```

Comment: The first and the third column i lose if i print the date thru date -d"$date" +%s

Comment: If you have GNU awk you can use [strftime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Comment: Also show your original data as your awk command looks a little complicated for the data you are getting out.

Comment: Do you have GNU awk? @123 - you mean `mktime()`, not `strftime()`. If only we had `strptime()` but we don't. Anyway, for the OP: Post the sample input that produces the output you posted. The first arg to `gsub()` is a regexp, btw, not a string so if you pass it a regexp then awk doesn't have to convert a string to a regexp and so you don't need to double escape metachars, e.g. you should be doing `gsub(/\[/, "")`, not `gsub("\\[", "")`. Right now by using a string where a regexp is expected you're doubling the work for yourself and for awk.

Comment: This is my RAW log file: [] ||  ||  ||  || [] || http || 40080 || 176.237.167.102 || [] || [-] || [0.072] || 176.237.167.102 || - || - || [25/Jan/2016:06:30:26 +0000] || "POST /checknewmsg HTTP/1.1" || 200 || 265 || 895 || "http://google.com/post” || "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36" || "-" || [TR]

Comment: No, edit your question. Don't try to put code, input, output, or other formatted text in a comment as you can't. And answer the question - do you have (or can you get) GNU awk?

Comment: OK, so now you've edited your question but you've only provided 1 line of input and that doesn't correspond to any of the lines of expected output. Look, it's extremely simple - post a few lines of sample input and the output you want to get from **that input**. Don't show us one set of input and then the output you want to get from some completely different set of input - that's not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've been a tad reluctant to provide the requested info in your question, idk if this is what you're looking for or not but with GNU awk for `mktime()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\\s*[|][|]\\s*" }
{
    split($15,a,/[][\/: ]/)
    a[3] = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[3])+2)/3
    secs = mktime(a[4]" "a[3]" "a[2]" "a[5]" "a[6]" "a[7])
    cnt[secs OFS $12]++
}
END {
    for (key in cnt) {
        print cnt[key], key
    }
}

$ cat file
[] ||  ||  ||  || [] || http || 40080 || 176.237.167.102 || [] || [-] || [0.072] || 176.237.167.102 || - || - || [25/Jan/2016:06:30:26 +0000] || "POST /checknewmsg HTTP/1.1" || 200 || 265 || 895 || "http://google.com/post” || "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36" || "-" || [TR]

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 1453725026 176.237.167.102
```

Comment: Yes, this is but i need to count the number of lines for the uniq timestamp and not the IP addresses even if they are printed. I`m using GNU awk. Thank you very much!

Comment: So, again (and for the last time), edit your question to provide sample input and the expected output given that input. In particular include a case where you have multiple IP addresses for 1 timestamp since you haven't described your requirements for output in that case at all and there's various ways you might want to handle it.